# Why the different wording between Shabbat Kiddush and zemirot?

Tags: shabbat, kiddush, shabbat-songs

In Leil Shabbat Kiddush we see the phrase:

**תחילה** למקראי קודש

Loose translation (mine): "The start of the holy callings (i.e. holy days)"

But in the Shabbat lunchtime somg *Yom Ze Mechubad*, we see the phrasing as:

**ראשון** הוא למקראי קודש

Loose translation (mine): "The first of the holy callings (i.e. holy days)"

Why is there a different word being used in each of these places? What is being conveyed in each of these places that might make that term more appropriate than the other?

Comment: The stanza in the poem needs to start with a ר

Comment: @DoubleAA Hah! That **could** be the only reason. hadn't considered that. Then again, the Kiddush, could have used the other term, as well.

Comment: @DanF But Kiddush predates the song by a great many years.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77506/759

Comment: @Adám I'm well aware of that, and also the idea that "poetry" has its freedoms. So, they need not match. There is an equal argument that might state that since Kiddush was much earlier, the author of Yom Ze Mechubad could have also been inspired by what was in Kiddush. OTOH, I also get DoubleAA's comment that it may be nothing more than getting the initials of his name in the zemer.